# Pandas DataFrame: Update two columns conditionally

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need to update 2 columns in Pandas DataFrame based on condition:
In a `col` I need to change 'bad' date to some values. And additionally - add a value which contains mark if `col` was changed or not.

Given

```
                    col
0  2005-01-01 00:00:00
1                  brk
2  2002-01-01 00:00:00
3                  NaN
```

I want to get

```
          col mark
0 2005-01-01    x
1 1999-09-09    z=(brk)
2 2002-01-01    x
3 1977-07-07    y
```

For this I've implemented following code (which works):

```
from datetime import datetime

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def safe_date(date_value):
    try:
        return (
            pd.to_datetime(date_value) if not pd.isna(date_value)
            else datetime(1977, 7, 7, 0, 0)
        )
    except:
        return datetime(1999, 9, 9, 0, 0)


def mark(date_value):
    try:
        pd.to_datetime(date_value)
        return (
            'x' if not pd.isna(date_value)
            else 'y'
        )
    except:
        return 'z=(' + date_value + ')'


data = {
    'col': [datetime(2005, 1, 1, 0, 0),
            'brk',
            datetime(2002, 1, 1, 0, 0),
            np.NaN]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print("before\n", df)

df['mark'] = df['col'].apply(mark)
df['col'] = df['col'].apply(safe_date)

print("after\n", df)
```

Though - here I need to have two similar functions `mark` and `safe_date` which is not safe (it is possible to forget to reflect changes in one of them). Additionally I suppose it is not efficient way.

I'm quite new to pandas dataframes.

Please suggest more optimal solution to a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `errors='coerce'` for possible convert also non parseable data, for `mark` column is used [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
t = datetime(1999, 9, 9, 0, 0)

#test missing values in original
m1 = df['col'].isna()
#convert to datetimes with replace missing values
#errors='coerce' is for missing values if no datetimes
df['col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col'].fillna('1977-07-07'), errors='coerce')
#check missing values created by to_datetime
m2 = df['col'].isna()
#replace by datetimes
df['col'] = df['col'].fillna(t)
#create column by 2 conditions
df['mark'] = np.select([m1, m2], ['y','z'], default='x')
print (df)
         col mark
0 2005-01-01    x
1 1999-09-09    z
2 2002-01-01    x
3 1977-07-07    y
```

EDIT:

```
t = datetime(1999, 9, 9, 0, 0)

#test missing values in original
m1 = df['col'].isna()
#added original data with `z` and ()
s = 'z=(' + df['col'].astype(str) + ')'
#convert to datetimes with replace missing values
#errors='coerce' is for missing values if no datetimes
df['col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col'].fillna('1977-07-07'), errors='coerce')
#check missing values created by to_datetime
m2 = df['col'].isna()
#replace by datetimes
df['col'] = df['col'].fillna(t)
#create column by 2 conditions, changed `z` to Series s
df['mark'] = np.select([m1, m2], ['y',s], default='x')
print (df)
         col     mark
0 2005-01-01        x
1 1999-09-09  z=(brk)
2 2002-01-01        x
3 1977-07-07        y
```

Comment: Hello @jezrael. Thank you for your answer. Just a small additional question - if i want to include original value with `z` mark - when value was not a valid date - how would i change a code?

Comment: @VladislavVarslavans - It should be new columns filled this values? Or instead `z` are this values?

Comment: @VladislavVarslavans - Can you edit question with expected output by this new requirement ?

Comment: Btw. Your code throws an error for me : `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "datetime.datetime") to str`. I've changed one line to fix that: `s = df['col'].apply(lambda l : 'z=(' + str(l) + ')')`

Comment: @VladislavVarslavans - Yop, ot another solution should be `s = 'z=(' + df['col'].astype(str) + ')'`